# How to Stop Oracle Java proccess ; eat internet bandwidth and processer

Tags: java, bandwidth

I installed oracle Java 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit. when i check my Internet bandwidth while do nothing on the Internet in **system monitor->resource**  data is sent and received.

When i look in process tab only Java process is using CPU and increase its size.
Why this process uploading and downloading data and how it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Java is probably getting updated/upgraded. You can stop this process if you don't want java to be updated. By right-clicking on the process when in System Monitor and clicking on "Kill process".

If this does not stop java, open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type the following:

```
sudo killall oracle-java*
```

This will kill all `oracle-java` processes on your system.

Comment: Thanks Jobin, i kill the process but it appears again after killing and start the same behavior. Is there any configuration to stop Java updates in Ubuntu.

Comment: I still have the same problem please help!